# how to use parameters in code behind to access some controls in my aspx file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 2 textbox that has a date values in my aspx file.  I would like to access these 2 controls in my select statement using code behind but i am getting error like this:
'Must declare the scalar variable "@txtStartClosingDate"
so what am i missing here in my code behind here?  thanks

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MainGridView.DataSource = GetData("select   GroupCategory, Count(Status1) as TotalCount from  [MasterProject] where Closing_Date >= @txtStartClosingDate and Closing_Date <= @txtEndClosingDate and Status1 is not null group by  GroupCategory");
            MainGridView.DataBind();


        }
    }
```

Here is one of the textbox that i am trying to reference:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartClosingDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You don't pass in any values for the query parameters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I highly recommend against this (due to SQL injection vulnerabilities), I think what you're trying to do is:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    MainGridView.DataSource = GetData("select   GroupCategory, Count(Status1) as TotalCount from  [MasterProject] where Closing_Date >= '"+ txtStartClosingDate.Text +"' and Closing_Date <= '"+ txtEndClosingDate.Text +"' and Status1 is not null group by  GroupCategory");
    MainGridView.DataBind();
}
```

What does the GetData method look like?  Does it take any SQL Parameters?

Comment: thanks for your quick response.  GetData method does not take any sql parameters.  So thanks for the tip but how can i avoid the sql injection possibility?

Comment: Modify GetData() so that it accepts parameters. If it's a general method, then make it accept a collection of SqlParameters for example, which you then can add into whatever SqlCommand, etc, that's actually doing the work

Answer (score 1):

Its bad practice to write sql queries in your code behind of aspx page. There are many solutions, one of them is using 3 layers structure application: GUI which is your aspx page, business logic layer which will handle the logic of your application and data access layer that will actually talk with the DB by calling queries or stored procedures, which actually is better than just writing the query in the code. Why? Because stored procedures gets compiled once in the DB and not like inline query which will be compiled every time, plus you can pass variables to the stored pricedure which will help you prevent sql injection.

Check out example of the architecture:

http://shoutingwords.com/creating-3-tier-layered-application-using-c-sharp.html

Stored procedures:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38682/Overview-of-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure